# How can I recreate an Instagram like scroll where the post information remains at the top until the next post reaches the top on Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, ipod, instagram

I want to recreate the Instagram scroll on Android. How can I do that? If you've never tried out Instagram, basically think of the "Alphabetical ordering" when you scroll through music on iPhones. You're scrolling through a bunch of songs which start with the letter "A". The letter A stays at the top of the screen until all songs that start with A are not on the display. The letter "B" pushes it away. How can I create something like this on Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Peter Kuterna's Pinned Header ListView](http://blog.peterkuterna.net/2011/05/pinned-header-listview-as-in-contacts.html).